# Infinity loop in paypal multi seller

Tags: api, rest, paypal

I'm currently programming a paypal multi seller checkout with the paypal api v2. In the checkout i always get stuck in a loop after clicking continue. It just says processing and stays like that. I also tried creating another Paypal App but same problem.How can i fix this? I used the following code to generate the order:

```
const axios = require('axios')

axios
  .post('https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders', {
        "intent":"CAPTURE",
        "application_context":{
        "return_url":"C:\Users\Felix\Desktop\index.html",
        "cancel_url":"C:\Users\Felix\Desktop\index.html"
    },
        "purchase_units":[
          {
             "reference_id":"test1",
             "payee": {
                    "email_address": "sb-lgj1x6610750@business.example.com"
             },
             "amount":{
                "currency_code":"EUR",
                "value":"100.00"
             },
             "payment_instruction":{
                "disbursement_mode":"INSTANT",
                "platform_fees":[
                   {
                      "amount":{
                         "currency_code":"EUR",
                         "value":"2.00"
                      }
                   }
                ]
             }
          },
          {
             "reference_id":"test2",
             "payee": {
                    "email_address": "sb-bong06236339@business.example.com"
             },
             "amount":{
                "currency_code":"EUR",
                "value":"7.00"
             },
             "payment_instruction":{
                "disbursement_mode":"INSTANT",
                "platform_fees":[
                   {
                      "amount":{
                         "currency_code":"EUR",
                         "value":"2.00"
                      }
                   }
                ]
             }
          }
        ]
  },{
      headers:{
            'Content-Type': "application/json",
            'Authorization': "Bearer A21AAJwo7sZjHVhLX3jHjR3HQzE-ojoUzbJUe--WXulQqOzEoV8sF0wNgCUqhOO3N3mDQl5pjnogxOBFmwywr3iXPpj9_VmGA",
            'PayPal-Partner-Attribution-Id': 'FLAVORsb-7vgls6637891_MP'
      }
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
    console.log(res.data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
```

Comment: The return_url must be a valid HTTP url, or it will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks. The only problem i got now is that after capturing the money is being tranken from the payer but does not get to the buyer. Any ideas what the problem is there?

Answer (score 0):

The return_url must be valid HTTP/S

The receiving (seller) account's email must be confirmed in the sandbox environment, https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email -- and if they do not have a balance in the transaction's currency (EUR in this example), they must accept a payment in their account's interface to open such a balance, or enable the payment receiving preference to automatically convert received payments to their account's primary balance (often USD, depending on country)